# How do I Escape an Ampersand in a REG_SZ String?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, regedit

I'm organizing my context menu for compiled binary tools and I wanted to use an ampersand *(&)* in one of the labels but nothing I have tried seems to work. I don't alter strings in the regisrty often and trying some of what I already know has not worked so far. I have tried the following:

```
^&
\&
\\&
@"Obfuscation & Packing"
&amp;
```

I'm not clear on what form of syntax the registry uses, it seems to be it's own thing compared to everything else I have worked with. How do I properly escape this character in a registry string?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

REG_SZ strings are just strings. They don't have anything that needs escaping.

*[Menu items](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/about-menus#menu-access-keys)* are where the `&` character becomes special. In menu item titles, it indicates that the following letter will become the keyboard shortcut (mnemonic) – e.g. `Ob&fuscation` will make the <kbd>F</kbd> key select the menu item, and the letter `f` will be underlined.

To escape the ampersand in menu items, it has to be doubled, e.g. `Obfuscation && Packing`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation. This got the job done, thanks again.